# Error running a Kotlin Ktor app on App Engine

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-platform, ktor

I'm trying to following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-ktor-app-engine-java8), to set a ktor app engine. I followed all the steps but when i have to run the application on localhost, i receive always:

```
Execution failed for task ':appengineRun'.
> com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.pro
cess.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
```

Any suggestion? Someone who already try that?

Comment: try with --stacktrace for verbose log and add the log here to find out about the root cause of the issue. With current log all we can know is that there is an exception in running the 'appengineRun gradle task.

Answer (score 0):

I understand an error is being thrown when following a guide to deploy a Kotlin App Engine application.

As of now, I am unable to reproduce the issue which you are facing, as I have downloaded the application as suggested and have found that the application deploys successfully and that it may run locally as well.

I would suggest attempting to do so as well, download the application [1] and see if you are able to access the application locally.

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kotlin-samples/tree/master/appengine/ktor/

Comment: Same problem, I cloned the repo and excuted "gradlew appengine Run" and the result was the same. Maybe is there something to set in my computer before? Thanks for help

Comment: As I believe you are attempting to run the application via your computer's terminal, have you installed the prerequisites and validated the Cloud Project as outlined by the [Using Gradle and the App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-gradle#linuxmacos) public documentation?